# Combine multiple sheets on excel

Tags: excel, merge

I have an excel file with around 30 sheets and different colomn headings. I am attempting to combine the sheets so that each sheet is placed after the next horizonally (with different colomn headings) on one combined sheet. The end result would be similar to copying and pasting each sheet after one another.

Thank you!!

Comment: Hi Jack, you may want to add VBA to the tags on this one.  I think VBA would be a good way to go.  Also here is a push in  the correct direction: http://analysistabs.com/excel-vba/copy-data-from-one-worksheet-to-another/

Comment: This question has been asked many times, what have you tried? Google and SO itself have many resources to do what you're trying to.  Please read through [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), try some things out, then let us know what specific code you're having trouble with. Searches would be for say, "VBA copy sheet to next empty row", or variations on that theme.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming here that you need to setup a destination worksheets which is auto-updated every time one or more of your source worksheets change. The below method will help accomplish this by referencing the columns of source spreadsheets into the destination spreadsheet by means of excel array formulas.

**1. Organize your source data** in separate 30 Worksheets/tabs within the same Excel Workbook. *If you will continue to receive your updated source data files, then this step will need to be modified to reference across the files*

**2. Insert a new Worksheet**, rename it to 'Combined', this will be your destination sheet

**3. Array Reference for Sheet1**

- Select as many number of columns in the destination worksheet starting from column A, as there are in the first Source worksheet
- press F2
- type the formula =Sheet1!A:B for referencing columns A to B, likewise change the range as required
- press Ctrl+Shift+Enter, this will convert your formula into an Array formula and all values from Sheet1 will get 'referenced' into the destination sheet

**4. Repeat the above step for subsequent worksheets** into the subsequent columns

At the end of this exercise, you have established a destination worksheet which will automatically pickup updated data as soon as you have a change to any of the source worksheets